# How to index array by one dimension only if I don't know the total number of dimensions?

Tags: julia

I have a (possibly multidimensional) array `X`. It has at least `k` dimensions. I don't know how many dimensions it has. How do I index it by `k`-th dimension only?

E.g. if `X` is 4-dimensional, `k` is 3, and the desired index is 7, I want to get `X[:, :, 7, :]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`selectdim`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.selectdim):

```
julia> X = reshape(1:2*3*5*7, 5, 3, 7, 2);

julia> selectdim(X, 3, 7)
5×3×2 view(reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 5, 3, 7, 2), :, :, 7, :) with eltype Int64:
[:, :, 1] =
 91   96  101
 92   97  102
 93   98  103
 94   99  104
 95  100  105

[:, :, 2] =
 196  201  206
 197  202  207
 198  203  208
 199  204  209
 200  205  210

julia> selectdim(X, 3, 7) == X[:, :, 7, :]
true
```

Comment: Nice. I can even do `selectdim(X, 3, 7:9)`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Matt's excellent answer, let me add that in these cases it's often the case that one axis has particular "meaning." In such cases, it's worth considering a package like [AxisArrays](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/AxisArrays.jl):

```
julia> using AxisArrays

julia> movie = AxisArray(rand(720, 1280, 50), :vertical, :horizontal, :time);

julia> timeslice = movie[Axis{:time}(5)];    # index along the time dimension

julia> size(timeslice)
(720, 1280)
```

This allows you to guarantee a meaningful outcome no matter how your data are stored. For example, the above code would take a time-slice even if `movie` were a 3d volume vs. time (e.g., MRI scan) rather than a 2d picture vs. time.